# How to automatically get user's timezone from client in Django?

Tags: python, django, timezone, region, django-timezone

I would like to know if there is a way to automatically retrieve user's timezone from client. Especially during login.

I tried to add this in the login page (using `auth.login`):

```
{% get_current_timezone as TIME_ZONE %}
```

Then, add this in the login form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/redirect/?tz={{ TIME_ZONE }}">
```

But, `tz` is always the timezone of the server.

Comment: This was discussed (and argued about) at length in another [SO question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/how-can-i-determine-a-web-users-time-zone).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/timezones/):

> Selecting the current time zone
>
> The current time zone is the
> equivalent of the current locale for translations. However, there's no
> equivalent of the Accept-Language HTTP header that Django could use to
> determine the user's time zone automatically. Instead, Django provides
> time zone selection functions. Use them to build the time zone
> selection logic that makes sense for you.

You can try setting timezone cookie via javascript by utilizing [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) function or try to do some geoip magic and figure timezone by location. Probably the most reliable way would be to ask the user directly and save this information in user profile/session.

Comment: Before you try to do 'geoip magic', take a look at @Rich's answer - it only took me a few minutes to pip install and configure his plugin.

Comment: sage, it doesn't work in 2022

Answer (score 14):

I've simplified it even further, and you can plug in in here: https://github.com/Miserlou/django-easy-timezones
or 
http://gun.io/blog/django-easy-timezones/

Comment: It's worth noting that this is available by pip and that there are step-by-step instructions.  I have it working after only a few minutes.  Thanks!

Comment: Any idea about performance impact? Especially in terms of response time.

Comment: django-easy-timezones uses an out of date database that is no longer available for download. Use django-easy-timelines-redux instead.

Comment: It is also worth noting that this package uses the client's IP address to look up the timezone, it isn't referencing the timezone setting of the client.

Answer (score 9):

I was hunting around for the sam thing yesterday. In the end I ended up putting together a Django app to what BluesRockAddict suggests above (i.e. use getTimezoneOffset):

https://github.com/adamcharnock/django-tz-detect

I hope someone finds that useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice APP for django to activate timezone https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-visitor-information-middleware/0.1.0. Which having two middleware

**TimezoneMiddleware**

*The middleware activates a timezone for an authenticated user.*

**VisitorInformationMiddleware**

*This middleware adds the following keys to the request.visitor dictionary:*

country - country the visitor is based in.

city - city the visitor is based in

location.timezone - timezone used in the location visitor is based in

location.unit_system - unit system used in the location visitor is based in

user.timezone - timezone of the currently authenticated user

user.unit_system - unit system of the currently authenticated user.

cookie_notice - True if a cookie consent notice should be displayed for the current visitor.

```
Note: Location of the user is determined based on the user's IP address.
```

Comment: Any idea about performance impact? Especially in terms of response time.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways without and with [django-tz-detect](https://github.com/adamcharnock/django-tz-detect) to automatically detect and apply the user's current timezone rather than applying only one timezone set to [TIME_ZONE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TIME_ZONE) in `settings.py`. *I recommend the way without `django-tz-detect` and I use **Django 4.2.3**.

First, create `middleware` folder with `__init__.py`(Empty file) and `custom.py` in `core/` and copy [base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html` in your virtual environment to `templates/admin/` as shown below. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322262/how-to-set-up-custom-middleware-in-django/76658256#76658256) explaining how to create **middlewares** and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist#answer-72359515) explaining how to set `templates` folder and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates#answer-76234344) explaining how to override [django admin templates](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin):

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-middleware # Here
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-custom.py
 |-my_app1
 |-my_app2
 └-templates
    |-my_app1
    |  └-base.html
    |-my_app2
    |  └-base.html
    └-admin
       └-base.html # Here
```

### <Without `django-tz-detect`>

Now, put the code below to `custom.py`:

```py
# "core/middleware/custom.py"

import zoneinfo
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render

class TimezoneMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        tz = request.COOKIES.get("mytz")
        if tz:
            timezone.activate(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(tz))
        else:
            timezone.activate(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("UTC"))
        return self.get_response(request)
```

Then, put `<script></script>` just before `</body>` in `templates/my_app1/base.html` and `templates/my_app2/base.html` as shown below:

```
{% "templates/my_app1/base.html" %}
{% "templates/my_app2/base.html" %}

<script>
let tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
if (!tz) {
    tz = "UTC"
}
document.cookie = "mytz=" + tz + ";path=/";
</script>
</body>
```

Then, put `<script></script>` just before `</body>` tag in `templates/admin/base.html` as shown below:

```
{% "templates/admin/base.html" %}

<script>
let tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
if (!tz) {
    tz = "UTC"
}
document.cookie = "mytz=" + tz + ";path=/";
</script>
</body>
```

Finally, set `TimezoneMiddleware` to [MIDDLEWARE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#middleware), then every time you load a django website, the user's current timezone is automatically detected and applied:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'core.middleware.custom.TimezoneMiddleware'
]
```

### <With `django-tz-detect`>

Now, install `django-tz-detect` as shown below:

```
pip install django-tz-detect
```

Then, set `tz_detect` and `TimezoneMiddleware` to [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps) and `MIDDLEWARE` respectively in `settings.py` as shown below. *Make sure that [django.template.context_processors.request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request) is set to [TEMPLATES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#templates)'s [OPTIONS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TEMPLATES-OPTIONS)'s `context_processors`:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'tz_detect' # Here
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'tz_detect.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware', # Here
]

...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates'
        ],
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.template.context_processors.request', # Here
                ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then, add the path below to `urlpatterns` in `core/urls.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('my_app1/', include('my_app1.urls')),
    path('my_app2/', include('my_app2.urls')),
    path('tz_detect/', include('tz_detect.urls')) # Here
]
```

Then, load `tz_detect.py`, then use `tz_detect` tag just before `</body>` tag in `templates/my_app1/base.html` and `templates/my_app2/base.html` as shown below:

```
{% "templates/my_app1/base.html" %}
{% "templates/my_app2/base.html" %}

{% load tz_detect %}
...
{% tz_detect %}
</body>
```

Finally, load `tz_detect.py`, then use `tz_detect` tag just before `</body>` tag in `templates/admin/base.html` as shown below:

```
{% "templates/admin/base.html" %}
                               {% ↓ Here ↓ %}
{% load i18n static i18n_switcher tz_detect %}<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<!-- END SVGs -->
{% tz_detect %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I currently created a middleware class (following Django's documentation) in which I rely on MaxMind geoip database (http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite) and GeoDjango (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/gis/) to retrive user's country code and then set the timezone dynamically using pytz:

```
class TimezoneMiddleware(object):


    def __getUserTimeZone(self, request):
        info = IPResolver(request).getGeoInfo()
        return pytz.country_timezones[info['country_code']][0]


    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            tz = self.__getUserTimeZone(request)
            timezone.activate(tz)
            logger.debug('Time zone "%s" activated' % str(tz))
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error('Unable to set timezone: %s' % str(e))
```

`pytz.country_timezones` returns a collection of time zones available for the given country, so I basically choose the first one returned.

`IPResolver` is a personal utility class I wrote on top of `django.contrib.gis.utils.GeoIP`

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in my program. In my js:

```
<script> 
  var today = new Date()
  var offset = today.getTimezoneOffset()
  const serializedData = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken={{ csrf_token }}&tz_offset= ' 
  + offset.toString() 
</script>
```

Then on the django side:

```
def your_function(request):
    tz_offset = request.POST.get('tz_offset')
    now = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=int(tz_offset))
    return now
```

I pass the serializedData into the POST request and then access that in my function

```
<script>
   function update_transaction(serializedData){
    $.post('{% url "your_url" %}', serializedData, function(data){
        //do stuff
    });
}
</script>
```