# Django timezone localization not working as expected

Tags: django, datetime, python-2.7, django-templates, timezone

I'm using Django 1.4.3 and Postgres 9.1.3. Here is my template where `message.created_at` is a python `datetime` object and it clearly tells me that the datetime object is stored in GMT as I can debug by passing `e` in `date` filter. The conversion to my local time which is IST is not happening though I used the block and filter given in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#template-tags). It still renders the date time value in GMT. What am I missing?

```
{% load tz %}
{% localtime on %}
<div class="m_td_block">
    <span>{{ message.created_at|date:"D, d M, Y e" }}</span>
    <span>{{ message.created_at|time:"h:i A" }}</span>
</div>
{% endlocaltime %}
```

Tried the another approach too,

```
{% load tz %}
<div class="m_td_block">
    <span>{{ message.created_at|localtime|date:"D, d M, Y e" }}</span>
    <span>{{ message.created_at|localtime|time:"h:i A" }}</span>
</div>
```

And this is my settings,

```
TIME_ZONE = 'GMT'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Have you tried using `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'` in your settings?

Comment: yes, I tried and it shows IST. But what if an another user from his location, for example `America/Chicago` view the same message?

Comment: You can use [timezone.activate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) as described.

Comment: @Babu - did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue with `stable/1.5.x`. I've never had this issue before today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Considering these posts [post#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone), [post#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235956/django-1-4-how-to-automatically-get-users-timezone-from-client) I'm gonna get the timezone manually from the user while signup and store it in database. And will go with `timezone.activate(request.user.timezone)`.

Comment: Did this fix it? I'm doing this now, without success.

Comment: Yes, that should fix it. Make sure that the middleware is getting executed. Official doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing an `activate` to activate the local time-zone? See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone).

Comment: Okay. If I add that middleware, do I need to set the `django_timezone` in request.sessions every time a session is created?