# Python/Django MySQL Datetime handling and timezone

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime, timezone

I've got a model called `Vote` with a field `date` :

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When I add an element, the date in MySQL is an UTC date but I live in UTC+2 timezone

I think I correctly set the timezone in `settings.py` :

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
```

Python use the right timezone :

```
>>> print datetime.datetime.now()
2013-07-03 09:05:04.474000
```

MySQL too :

```
> SELECT NOW( )
2013-07-03 09:00:48
```

I could set the date attribute manualy, it works but I would like to know why auto_now_add return a wrong date although python and mysql use the right timezone

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a complex binding to explain. From [Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone),

> When USE_TZ is False, **this** is the time zone in which Django will store
>   all datetimes. When USE_TZ is True, **this** is the default time zone that
>   Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret
>   datetimes entered in forms.

**this** refers to `TIME_ZONE`. So what is your `USE_TZ`? If your `USE_TZ` is True then Django will store datetime in UTC and use `TIME_ZONE` to display in templates and interpret forms.

This is because, if you change your `TIME_ZONE` later when hosting your site in another territory, it's easy to convert any datetimes from UTC to any timezones given.

In [Django 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#time-zone) and earlier,

> Note that **this** is the time zone to which Django will convert all
>   dates/times – not necessarily the timezone of the server. For example,
>   one server may serve multiple Django-powered sites, each with a
>   separate time-zone setting.
>
> Normally, Django sets the os.environ['TZ'] variable to the time zone
>   you specify in the TIME_ZONE setting. Thus, all your views and models
>   will automatically operate in the correct time zone.

But doesn't tell you in what timezone the datetime will be stored in database. Need to experiment anyway(my guess is UTC).

`print datetime.datetime.now()` prints the datatime according to the timezone setup of your server machine unless you have opened the python console via `manage.py shell`.

Same goes for MySQL console. It shows the datetime in your machine timezone rather than what's stored in database if I'm right.

Comment: My USE_TZ was set to True, I prefer to store the date in the local timezone, so I set USE_TZ to False and It works ! Thank you

Comment: Please remember that if you set it to `False` then you'll deal with great pain while localizing your application. I'd prefer to store it in UTC and write a middleware to set the timzone for the current request. If you have time, spend some to research on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065338/django-timezone-localization-not-working-as-expected :)

Comment: Ok, my application is not supposed to be localized. But I keep that in mind for a next dev. Thank's very useful comment