# what is the right way in django timezone setting

Tags: python, django, django-models, timezone, django-timezone

I just followed instructions on django website https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/ and TodayArchiveView was showing the date for the next day.

my setting TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' and I changed it to TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles' and TodayArchiveView worked but is this the right way? what if a user is in europe will he get the right time zone?

Comment: give me the url, i'll test it for you :) (germany)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your user will not see right time zone, because Django doesn't have a way to get user timezone as far as I know and it was also stated, [here see accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235956/django-1-4-how-to-automatically-get-users-timezone-from-client). You have three choices to get this right:

1. Get user timezone with some javascript, [take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone)
2. Get user timezone with some geolocation method, like [django-easy-timezones](https://github.com/Miserlou/django-easy-timezones)
3. Ask user for his timezone and save it in his profile, [then you can activate user timezone in view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone)