# Django. Display correct time - depending on time zone

Tags: python, django, timezone

What is the best way to display time according to the user's time zone?

I have a Post object:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   submit_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   ...
```

In the template I have something like this:

```
{% load tz %}
<p> TIME: {{ post_object.submit_date|localtime }} </p>
```

In settings.py:

```
USE_TZ = True
USE_L10N = True
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Probably I'm missing something obvious, all I want is the template to display the user's time depending on its timezone. Should I do some logic on the views.py file?

Comment: How do you know what the user's time zone is?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17209771/263989

Answer (score 2):

It depends on django version and on user time zone. If you have user time zone stored in user's profile or somewhere else you can use [`timezone`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone) template tag:

```
{% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
    Paris time: {{ value }}
{% endtimezone %}
```

Or you can use [timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/timezones/#std:templatefilter-timezone) filter:

```
{{ value|timezone:"Europe/Paris" }}
```

Otherwise you'll have to find out what's user's timezone is (by her ip I think). So you can use solution provided by fasouto [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235956/django-1-4-how-to-automatically-get-users-timezone-from-client/17209771#17209771) (but it's not reliable for it returns first timezone for the country, and there are countries with several time zones).

PS: I think that best bet is to ask user for her time zone and store it for it's sure way to provide proper date/time display for her.