# converting time in django

Tags: django, datetime, django-rest-framework

hi i'm new in working with `datetime` objects in django
all I know now is that instead of python's `datetime.datetime.now()` we should use django's `timezone.now()`, i've also set `TIMEZONE` and `USE_TZ=True` in settings.py
but my problem is now for converting these types of time. as far as I know, even if we use `timezone.now()` for saving in database, django uses UTC time to store in DB. so I need a simple syntax for converting UTC time into my local time which is set in settings.py and vice versa to get local time from human and return local time.
i've also seen that django has some template tags to do that, but since i am doing this mostly for a REST API with `django-rest` for an android app, i need to be able to do this in python syntax.
thanks everyone, I hope I could be clear at what I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

In templates, Django will automatically convert your model dates (stored as UTC) to the current time zone.  The current time zone is set by `settings.TIMEZONE` unless you explicitly change it somewhere else.  You don't even need to use special template tags.  This will convert fine:

`{{ MyModel.my_date }}`

Outside of templates, there is a tool called `localtime` that you can use to do the same conversion.

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

...
local_date = localtime(MyModel.my_date)
print( str(MyModel.my_date) )    # UTF time
print( str(local_date) )         # local time
```

The datetime returned by `localtime` is [time zone aware](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).  If you ever need a time zone naive datetime, you can convert it like this:

```
my_date = localtime(MyModel.my_date).replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Comment: thanks, very helpful, but i also need to get local time from user and save its converted to UTC in db. what is the best way for that?!

Comment: To the best of my understanding, that conversion is automatic.  If you're using a ModelForm to get user input, for example, Django will assume any datetime inputs are in the user's local time, and will convert to UTC when saving to the database.

Comment: Oh, and if you're asking how to get a user's real local time zone instead of using `settings.TIMEZONE`, that's not so easy to do.  See the answers for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235956/django-1-4-how-to-automatically-get-users-timezone-from-client).

Comment: "In templates, Django will automatically convert your model dates (stored as UTC) to the user's time zone." I do not believe this statement to be correct. Can you cite from the documentation?

Comment: [Time zone aware output in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-output-in-templates)   - Note, by "user's time zone" I was referring to what Django calls the "current time zone".  As I mentioned in an above comment, Django doesn't have a way to automatically determine a user's actual time zone.  I will correct the terminology in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If, in settings.py we have the following:

```
from pytz import timezone
LOCAL_TZ = pytz.timezone('CST6CDT') # asume that local timezone is central, but you can use whatever is accurate for your local
```

Now, you can use this to convert from utc time to local

```
import pytz
from django.conf import settings

def to_local_dttm(utc_dttm):
    return utc_dttm.astimezone(settings.LOCAL_TZ)

def to_utc_dttm(local_dttm):
    return local_dttm.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```