# Set timezone relative to user in django

Tags: python, django

I made a web app using django, I'm not sure about the timezones and stuff. I have the user's preferred timezone, how can I set this timezone relative to that particular user? or will it automatically adjust to the user's timezone?

Comment: read about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48028119/7618968

Answer (score -1):

You can set the time zone that you want django to use in the settings.py

eg
settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
```

Comment: I have multiple users using the app, each of their timezones will be different.

Comment: then you'll have to use  pytz package. link>> http://pytz.sourceforge.net/