# How to show local time in html?

Tags: html, css, django

I have the Django project with the Model to save date_added information. Here's the Model code.

```
class Outputting(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I want to retrieve such date_added information and demonstrate it as the local time in the html. How could I make the transformation? Here's the view.py and html template, but it still show the UTC time.

view.py

```
def results(request):
    user = request.user
    data = Outputting.objects.filter(owner=user).order_by('id').values_list('id','date_added')
    return render(request, "xx.html", {"data": data})
```

Html:

```
<tr>
{% for i in data %}
<td style="word-wrap:break-word;"><div class="panel-body" type="datetime-local"><small>{{ i.1|date:'M d Y H:i:s' }}</small></div></td>
</tr class="something">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **settings.py** change the time zone location

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Abidjan'
```

if you don't know your location you can list all available `time_zone` options by running below command in the Django shell:

```
In [40]: import pytz
In [41]: pytz.all_timezones
Out[42]: 
['Africa/Abidjan',
 'Africa/Accra',
 'Africa/Addis_Ababa',
 ...]
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13867319/7470786

**EDIT:**

For this, you should dynamically get the location of the user. After searching I came across with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10236012/7470786) which suggest using [getTimeZoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset).

Comment: Thx. But if I upload such app online, for the other users try to retrieve their localtime, should I add the specific timezone in the setting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable `USE_TZ = True` in your `settings.py` if you not.
In order to have value in localtime in the template you can do:

```
{% load tz %}

{% localtime on %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```

Also you can set specific timezone like:

```
{% load tz %}

{% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
    Paris time: {{ value }}
{% endtimezone %}
```

Or if you need one value to be converted you can do:

```
{% load tz %}

{{ value|localtime }}
```

You can read more in Django official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#template-tags).

Comment: Thx. But if I upload such app online, for the other users try to retrieve their localtime that may be not mine, should I add the specific timezone in the setting?

Comment: If you want to have only specific timezone you can set it in settings.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to set specific timezone. Just let the program to identify it and show it based on the user's timezone. Can it do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it in UTC and display it in the local time, then do this

```
 {% load tz %}

 {% timezone "Asia/Kolkata" %}
   India time: {{ value }}  #Add your respective time
 {% endtimezone %}

 {% timezone None %}
    Server time: {{ value }}
 {% endtimezone %}
```

This will return UTC if no time zone is given.

Note that - Conversion to local time is not always appropriate.
Also check out the warning inside [Official Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-output-in-templates)