# Setting time zone according to user's Country

Tags: python, django, time, timezone

I am building a BlogApp AND i am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to store timezone in every field ( post date, comment date ) according to `User's Country`.

> Suppose, A user is registered account on webapp from `Brazil` then i am trying to automatically set time zone of Brazil for the `User`.

But i have tried many answers [LIKE THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235956/django-1-4-how-to-automatically-get-users-timezone-from-client)  and [LIKE THIS](https://github.com/paluh/django-tz) but nothing worked for me. Some told that it should be done through `JavaScript` BUT i have no idea idea how can i do it.

When i try to register then it automatically sets the `timezone` which i have settled in `settings.py`.

**TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'**

**What have i tried :-**

- I have also tried **localize**  ( according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/formatting/#overview) ) BUT still showing the same time.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(null=True,default=timezone.now)
```

settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

new_post.html

```
{% load l10n %}

{% localize on %}
    {{ form.date_added|as_crispy_field }}
{% endlocalize %}
```

all_posts.html

```
{% load l10n %}

{% localize on %}
    {{ post.date_added|as_crispy_field }}
{% endlocalize %}
```

> I have set `UTC` in settings BUT i am in `Asia/Kolkata` timezone. So it should localize the `timezone` into my Local Time. BUT it is still in `UTC`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: See [Format localization (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/formatting/)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, Will it also change `timezone` according to user's country ?

Comment: Why change the settings for each user? Django will automatically try to localize any date / time formats, timezones etc. according to a users locale as long as `USE_L10N` is set to `True`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, How django will know which country i am in AND which time zone to convert ?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, I have edited my question, Please have a look.