# Django - Working With different Timezones

Tags: django, timezone

I am working on a Django application on Dietitian Portal, in which there are client from different countries.Now For appointment booking for client i need to send availabe time slots to user according to dietitian's timezone. Now the problem is that if dietitian's timezone is Asia/Calcutta and client's timezone is Us/Eastern or other.when the client is requesting for slots than there is a date 19 and accoring to dietitian's timezone 20th, So how can i manage this that i can cover the whole day of dietitian in client's timezone

It works Fine if date is same but if two different dates are there than the problem comes.Client is not able to fetch slots of dietitian because
according to dietitian's timezone date is 20th.

Comment: check the latest release for the timezone and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/
Here is a useful link for the same have a look to this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061911/django-with-system-timezone-setting-vs-users-individual-timezones

Comment: You need to show your models and the query you're using to fetch the slots. Basically, you need to convert the current datetime (e.g. `now()`) to the right timezone before running your query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take a similar approach to the steps mentioned in the [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone):

First, get Timezone info from user:

```
from pytz import country_timezones

class User(...):
    country_code = models.CharField(...)

    def get_tz_info(self):
       return country_timezones(self.country_code)[0]
```

Then, write a [**`MIDDLEWARE`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE) to activate localized timezone:

```
import pytz

from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class TimezoneMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        tzname = request.user.get_tz_info()
        if tzname:
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzname))
        else:
            timezone.deactivate()
```

Comment: Thanx i will look into this

Answer (score 0):

You can use UTC Timezone - [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/). You can find this code in your settings.py, if not put this -

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Your browser will automatically convert to local timezones